# Can I have VS2010 change the environment settings based on the project loaded?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, settings

*see title*

For example: Open a C++ project, it opens using the C++ environment settings or an arbitrary environment settings file. Then open a C# project and then it opens using the C# environment settings or an arbitrary environment settings file.

Or should I honestly not care and just use the interface I already set up? What advantages would there really be for switching them per project/project type?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe [Perspectives](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/d446d9d3-4994-4d78-853d-f266b0bfd4ec) extension can help you. After installing you can save your current layout as perspective (just like in Eclipse) in Visual Studio 2010.